# How can Flow be forced to cast a value to another type?

Tags: casting, flowtype

Is it possible to forcibly cast a variable in [Flow](https://flowtype.org)?

```
type StringOrNumber = string | number
const foo: StringOrNumber = 'hello'

// I look for something like `const bar:string = (string) foo`
const bar: string = foo // fails
const bar: string = (foo: string) // also fails
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Flow doesn't do direct casting from one type to another, but you can do something like

```
const bar: string = (foo: any);
```

so you cast `foo` to an `any`, because `any` accepts any type of value as an input. Then because the `any` type also allows you to read all possible types from it, you can assign the `any` value to `bar` because an `any` is also a `string`.

Answer (score 27):

In the example you give you're looking at a "cast" from a union type to one of its members. While it's common to think of this as a cast, it's not the same as type-casting in other languages.

By setting the type of `foo` to `string | number`, we've told Flow that this value could be either a string or a number. We then happen to put a string in it, but Flow doesn't discard our direct assertion about its type because of that, even in situations (like this one) where it couldn't change later.

To assign it to a `string`-typed variable, Flow needs to know that even though it might have been either a `string` or `number`, by the time we do the assignment we are sure that it can only be a `string`.

This process of reducing the possible options is called **type refinement**.

### Type refinements

To refine the type, we need to prove that it must be the type we say it is, *in a way Flow understands*.

In the original example, you could do this using `typeof`:

```javascript
type StringOrNumber = string | number
const foo: StringOrNumber = 'hello'

// This would raise an error here:
// const bar: string = foo

if (typeof foo === "string") {
  // Flow now knows that foo must be a string, and allows this.
  const bar: string = foo
}
```

Not everything that a human can see as a type refinement is understood by Flow, so sometimes you'll need to look at [the refinement docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/) to see what might make Flow understand it.

### Suppression comments

Sometimes there's no way to express the safety of a refinement to Flow. We can force Flow to accept a statement through use of a [suppression comment](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex), which will suppress an error Flow would otherwise report. The default suppression comment is `$FlowFixMe`, but it can be configured to a different comment or comments.

Flow will report an error on the second line of this, reporting that unionValue might be of type 'number':

```javascript
const unionValue: StringOrNumber = 'seven'
const stringValue: string = unionValue
```

However, by using a suppression comment, this passes Flow:

```javascript
const unionValue: StringOrNumber = 'seven'
// $FlowFixMe: We can plainly see this is a string!
const stringValue: string = unionValue
```

One useful feature of suppression comments is that a suppression comment without a following error to suppress is considered an error. If we change the type in the example:

```javascript
const unionValue: string = 'seven'
// $FlowFixMe: Even though this is a string, suppress it
const stringValue: string = unionValue
```

Now Flow will report an "Unused suppression" error instead, alerting us. This is particularly useful when Flow should be able to recognize a refinement but can't - by using a suppression comment, we're alerted to remove the comment (and gain additional type-safety) if a future version of Flow recognizes the code as type-safe.

### Cast-through-any

If you really can't express it in a way that demonstrates its safety to flow, and you can't (or won't) use a suppression comment, you can cast any type to `any`, and `any` to any type:

```javascript
const unionValue: StringOrNumber = 'seven'
// Flow will be okay with this:
const stringValue: string = (unionValue: any)
```

By casting a value to `any` we're asking Flow to forget anything it knows about the type of the value, and assume whatever we're doing with it must be correct. If we later put it into a typed variable, Flow will assume that must be right.

### Cautions

It's important to note that both suppression comments and cast-through any are *unsafe*. They override Flow completely, and will happily perform completely nonsensical "casts":

```javascript
const notAString: {key: string, key2: number} = {key: 'value', key2: 123}
// This isn't right, but Flow won't complain:
const stringValue: string = (notAString: any)
```

In this example, `stringValue` is holding the `object` from `notAString`, but Flow is sure that it's a string.

To avoid this, **use refinements that Flow understands** whenever you can, and avoid use of the other, unsafe "casting" techniques.

Comment: Is $FlowFixMe preferable to an any cast? Or are they roughly equivalent?

Comment: @Casebash - They're mostly equivalent, but (as I tried to clarify in the answer) a suppression comment is more future-proof. If a subsequent version of Flow learns how to recognize the refinement you're performing, the suppression comment will notify you that it's not suppressing anything anymore.

I'd appreciate any ideas on how to edit the answer to make this clearer!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just a suggestion. When browsing around solutions to Event and HTMLElement related type checking issues I encountered a lot of guards invoking instanceof.

To satisfy type checks I just introduced this generic guard and called it `cast` (which does not of course make it a cast), because otherwise my code got so bloated.

The cost is of course in performance (pretty relevant when writing games, but I guess most use cases benefit more from type guards than milliseconds per iteration).

```js
const cast = (type : any, target : any) => {
    if (!(target instanceof type)) {
        throw new Error(`${target} is not a ${type}`);
    }
    return target;
}
```

Usages:

```js
const fooLayer = cast(HTMLCanvasElement, document.getElementById("foo-layer"));
window.addEventListener("click", (ev : Event) =>
  console.log(cast(MouseEvent, ev).clientX - cast(HTMLElement, ev.target).offsetLeft,
    cast(MouseEvent, ev).clientY - cast(HTMLElement, ev.target).offsetTop));
```

Answer (score 1):

An update, perhaps, on one or more of the existing answers:  There is currently a fairly nice way to specifically tell Flow not to worry about what it thinks is a bad cast.

You can give an error suppression directive with a specific error code, like this:

```javascript
type StringOrNumber = string | number
const foo: StringOrNumber = 'hello'

// I look for something like `const bar:string = (string) foo`
// const bar: string = foo // would fail
// $FlowExpectedError[incompatible-cast]
const baz: string = (foo: string) // no longer fails!!
```

As an extra bonus, here is yet another way to perform the cast without any complaint from Flow:

```javascript
/*:: if (typeof foo !== "string") throw null; */
const baz: string = (foo: string) // does not fail!!
```

Here the special `/*::` syntax tells Flow that it should treat the text within the comment (other than the colons) as if it were normal JavaScript code.  I gather from the documentation that this feature exists to provide a way to decorate your code with Flow-specific syntax without preventing it from also functioning as pure JavaScript - which has the modest benefit of allowing Flow to be used without any Flow-syntax-stripping tool like Babel or whatever.  But the feature also works nicely as a mechanism for expressing "assertions" that only Flow can read.  It's a bit hacky, but I personally think it's clean enough to use in a serious project!  I mean, as long as you only do it once in a while...

Of course you could leave the `typeof` check in actual JavaScript that will actually run, but that could conceivably have a runtime cost I imagine?  This, on the other hand, will surely not.