# How to mock a flow type compatible dom class File

Tags: mocha.js, flowtype

I'm trying to get a mocha spec to fabricate a [`File`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.53.1/lib/dom.js#L47) as enforced by flow type.

The following yields `^^^^^^ object literal. This type is incompatible with File`.

What is the proper way to do this?

```
/**
 *
 *   declare class Blob {
 *    constructor(blobParts?: Array<any>, options?: {
 *      type?: string;
 *      endings?: string;
 *    }): void;
 *    isClosed: bool;
 *    size: number;
 *    type: string;
 *    close(): void;
 *    slice(start?: number, end?: number, contentType?: string): Blob;
 *  }
 *  
 *   declare class File extends Blob {
 *    constructor(
 *      fileBits: $ReadOnlyArray<string | BufferDataSource | Blob>,
 *      filename: string,
 *      options?: FilePropertyBag,
 *    ): void;
 *    lastModifiedDate: any;
 *    name: string;
 *  }
 *  
 * @param name
 * @param type
 * @returns {*}
 */
function newFile (name: string, type?: string): File {
  const result = { name, type }
  return (result: File)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force casting in Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328728/force-casting-in-flow)

Answer (score 0):

Flow uses ["nominal typing"](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/nominal-structural/#nominal-typing-a-classtoc-idtoc-nominal-typing-hreftoc-nominal-typinga) for classes. This means just having an object with the same keys and value types can't stand in for an actual instance of the class. I suspect the best thing to do is just make your own subclass of `File` that overrides the fields/methods you want. If you override fields/methods, you may want to review the [variance rules](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/) so you don't get type errors from your subclass.