# Flow error when using dynamic function references

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

I have a function in a React project which iterates through an array and compares each item with another variable. Now the items in the array can be either string or regular expression. So I keep a variable called `compareFn` and point its reference to either `equal` or `patternMatch` based on item's type. Below is the sample code.

```
const equal = (privilege: string, whitelistVal: string) => privilege === whitelistVal;
const patternMatch = (privilege: string, whitelistPattern: RegExp) => whitelistPattern.test(privilege);

...

const compareFn = whitelistItem instanceof RegExp ? patternMatch : equal;
if (compareFn(privilegeItem, whitelistItem)) {
  // Do something
}
```

With this code, I am getting a flow error highlighting `whitelistItem` in line 36 like below:

> Cannot call compareFn with whitelistItem bound to whitelistPattern
>   because string [1] is incompatible with RegExp [2].
>
> 35|       const compareFn = whitelistItem instanceof RegExp ?
>   patternMatch : equal;
>   36|       if (compareFn(privilegeItem, whitelistItem)) {

To me, it looks like Flow doesn't recognize the conditional assignment of the function reference. Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated.

I'm using Flow 0.71.0 and React Native 0.55.3.

Comment: Do you get that same error if you use `var` instead of `const`? Consider also wrapping your conditional test in parentheses: `(whitelistItem instanceof RegExp) ? ...`

Comment: Getting the same error for both options

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328728/how-can-flow-be-forced-to-cast-a-value-to-another-type - this might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works:

```
const equal = (privilege: string, whitelistVal: string) => privilege === whitelistVal;
const patternMatch = (privilege: string, whitelistPattern: RegExp) => whitelistPattern.test(privilege);


declare function getCompareFn(
  whitelistItem: RegExp
): (string, RegExp) => boolean;
declare function getCompareFn(
  whitelistItem: string
): (string, string) => boolean;

function getCompareFn(whitelistItem) {
  return whitelistItem instanceof RegExp ? patternMatch : equal;
}

const whitelistItem1 = /test/;
const whitelistItem2 = "test";

const privilegeItem = "test";

getCompareFn(whitelistItem1)(privilegeItem, whitelistItem1);
getCompareFn(whitelistItem2)(privilegeItem, whitelistItem2);
```

Link to [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBApgRwK4EMA2MC8MAUAHAJwEsA3ItOAczgC4ZpixKAaGAdwAsio40joAaujoMiTAJRYAfDEKlyVOFkzZO3XvyhC0AbgBQoSLDwooPAmACyp4Byy45ZCtRFRGLdlx59oABVPmYHQASlQAogAeeJKYMmremv5mcBYAdDzQ+MROiuL6enoAJnDAaCgESgBmSGDAUETgMNRQAMIgALYmFQBiYDjxGtAAkjztIeFR4nQ4okysoZSR0dIwAEYgIBQoYPrFpeVVNXUNYE1wrR1dcL39XoNQI3Bj9G5ilFO4sx5fMTLrm3BtvlqrV6o1mm1OgcbgMfA9RpIAN56GAwCpQJAWTzqOGPdowMTQbbAOAgSowBZLGAAflkARSVhsdjoiFQuj0AF8CoZoNiEsNRgBGewAegyUBF+h5sFhmjxACZ7AAicVK-LS2TZBTUPHK1X5CGXaF9WUCp6C8RZeTOOB41im+HmvJ6Q1Qnomu640byy2ObW20b2z1y715IA)

Flow's [`declare`](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/) is used to pin down the precise type signature of `getCompareFn` that would be otherwise difficult to express. Note flow does not enforce your declare's correctness, so it's your responsibility to carefully analyze and ensure the declared types indeed matches the function's implementation, in this example though, this is fairly trivial.

Without using `declare`, here's what we can do:

```
// type alias to represent generic compare function
type CompareFn<T> = (string, T) => boolean;

function getCompareFn(
  whitelistItem: RegExp | string
): CompareFn<string> | CompareFn<RegExp> {
  return whitelistItem instanceof RegExp ? patternMatch : equal;
}
```

So far so good, it type checks. (Note however, the return value of `getCompareFn` is not `CompareFn<RegExp | string>`). Unfortunately, this type specification of `getCompareFn` is not precise enough. For example, we know the following is true:

```
const f: CompareFn<string> = getCompareFn('string');
```

Yet, flow cannot assert that.

One step further, we may attempt this to fix the problems:

```
function getCompareFn<T: RegExp | string>(whitelistItem: T): CompareFn<T> {
  return whitelistItem instanceof RegExp ? patternMatch : equal;
}
```

This is much better than above, as it's more precise, the generic function `getCompareFn` states:

1. `getCompareFn(string) -> CompareFn<string>`
2. `getCompareFn(RegExp) -> CompareFn<RegExp>`

Which is exactly the code's intention. All is good? Unfortunately this code does not typecheck. The problem is `T: string | RegExp`, which states: for all subtypes of type `string | RegExp`, `getCompareFn` returns `CompareFn<T>`. Which translates to:

1. `getCompareFn(string) -> CompareFn<string>`
2. `getCompareFn(RegExp) -> CompareFn<RegExp>`
3. `getCompareFn(string | RegExp) -> CompareFn<string | RegExp)`;

The last case is obviously not true, as `getCompareFn` can never return a compare function that accepts both string and RegExp. So we want to expression case 1 and 2, but not allow for case 3, and the only instrument I know of to do so is `declare`, thus the solution first outlined in this answer.

Lastly, by changing the code a bit, Here's a solution without using `declare`, and a little bit more idiomatic (in my opinion): [Link](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBA7gCwJZQKYBsnQJJoLYCMMAvDAPRrRkDcAUKJLIihllLqngEwkwBElKHzr1w0GAAcATkgBuSdKgDmqDnl4DU0YbVpIwaKQDMAhsFQwAKlqgBlKDLBKYAb1owYggBQQAXDGhHJQBKfwAjEBBFEzBqD1oAXxEyMhgAJWUAUQAPCRgEEwgYPFQoBBAAExgAA0FqgBpPBFQpVCMQVoCHAFdgKG6pE3R0AE8YJDwJRRKDIutoeyDdYHRCosyAR26hiEX9ZwmpzlRZqxs9p1d3DwB9WSHu1H9A-boPGAZA3qgOr3v0R7PBz7YJXd7vMpYAB0dweFlI-0ecWuMASKO8EFBbnBHla-SkYACJGIpEhEBhiNQyPeaLRtCM3TAfSQ4BgKjswKc80MXmYaEwOHwQKCMAAPuksrlQmcFpznNjxkYYLzkPy2GpxowYuYQEqMkochIsSiYHiBoS+axBZw3qiYBgIBYFbjSuaYGBUHAYJttuhdnKVSwBex8MFbbTlmJYFAiKR2RclNyWoG1dbCGHRIxPDw46UE0mpCmrSHOFwM5nxGECOFItFCaSCFDvNI5AplKpQ3RPrAwlwa1FUDFeFAuE2bF4W-JFCo1GGgA).

```
const whitelistItem1 = /test/;
const whitelistItem2 = "test";

const privilegeItem = "test";

interface TestString {
  test(s: string): boolean;  
};

// RegExp has method `test`, therefore structurally implements TestString

class EqualsString implements TestString {
   _value: string;
   constructor(value: string) {
      this._value = value; 
   }
   test(s) {
      return s === this._value; 
   }
}

function getStringTester(whitelistItem: string | RegExp): TestString {
  if (whitelistItem instanceof RegExp) {
    return whitelistItem;
  } else {
    return new EqualsString(whitelistItem);
  }
}

const t1 = getStringTester(whitelistItem1);
const t2 = getStringTester(whitelistItem2);

const b1: boolean = t1.test(privilegeItem);
const b2: boolean = t2.test(privilegeItem);
```